# NAT table in iptables rules and SNAT

Tags: iptables, nat

I am new to iptables and I would appreciate some help understanding a specific rule in the nat table of a router. The router's external interface is vlan2 (111.111.111.111) and the internal interface is br0 (192.168.1.1). Here is the nat section, with line numbers in front of every rule.

```
    (1) *nat
    (2) -A PREROUTING -d 111.111.111.111 -j WANPREROUTING
    (3) -A PREROUTING -i vlan2 -d 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0 -j DROP
    (4) -A WANPREROUTING -p tcp  --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.12:22
    (5) -A POSTROUTING  -o vlan2 -j MASQUERADE
    (6) -A POSTROUTING -o br0 -s 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0 -d 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.1
    (7) COMMIT
```

1. The rule in question is on line #6.  I am struggling to understand why it is needed. It looks like it is rewriting the source address of every packet routed through br0 interface to the internal router's address 192.168.1.1, but I am not sure.
2. Can this section be rewritten as

   ```
   (1) *nat
   (2) -A PREROUTING -i vlan2 -d 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0 -j DROP
   (3) -A PREROUTING -i vlan2 -p tcp  --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.12:22
   (4) -A POSTROUTING  -o vlan2 -j MASQUERADE
   (5) -A POSTROUTING -o br0 -s 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0 -d 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.1
   (6) COMMIT
   ```

by removing WANPREROUTING chain?

Thanks!